# Getting partial NEW.<value> using AFTER INSERT trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I'm trying to learn PostgreSQL. Now I came across a triggers, and I've wanted to create a trigger to 'copy' inserted data to another table.

I've managed to put together a function and an trigger. But every time I attempt to insert the data, I get partial data to the NEW.nameOfTheRow.

Image as Example on data that I should receive in the **user_entity table**:
[image: Image of the data in the table user_entity]

And here is the data that is getting inserted by the function in the **Employee table**:
[image: Image of the data in the table Employee]

**And here's the table user_entity:**

[image: Image of the table Employee]

**Here is the table "Employee":**

[image: Image of the table user_entity]

Here's the code for the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER sync_two_tables_on_insert
    AFTER INSERT ON user_entity
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE sync_employee_with_keycloak_entity();
```

And here's the code for the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sync_employee_with_keycloak_entity() RETURNS trigger AS $$
  BEGIN
  -- This script is not optimized by all means, it will attempt to add data with brute force,
  -- Ideally, we would like to do some checking's before attempting to transfer data,
  -- "Type" row is not 'valid' here, as the data is not correct, the only reason I've put it there is because it is set to Not Null
  -- TODO: Optimize whole script, make validation checks, add error handlers, filter to not pass duplicates.
     INSERT INTO "Employees" ("Id", "Email", "FirstName", "LastName", "Alias", "Type")
     VALUES(new.id::uuid, new.email, new.first_name, new.last_name, new.username, new.not_before)
     ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
    RETURN NULL;
  END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I don't understand why I don't get new data on NEW.email, NEW.first_name, NEW.last_name
But I do get correct data on NEW.id, NEW.username and NEW.not_before.

Comment: Please create an [MCVE], ideally on an on-line DB playground for example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk)

Comment: There are some possibilities: 1) you really insert a NULL value for `user_entity.email` 2) the actual value in `"Employees"."Email"` is not NULL 3) there is a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger or an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` rule on `"Employees"` that modifies the row.

Comment: Slightly off topic: don’t use uppercase characters in your table and column names. You will always forget some double quotes “ somewhere, just too much work and frustration without any gains

Comment: Hello, I've tried to reproduce the problem on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/p8ZdySxv), but it worked as intended. Which leaves me with a possibility that something is different on how KeyCloak insert data in database(?).